# Does Metal clip points to the center?

Tags: graphics, 3d, metal

When rendering with points that have a large point size, under desktop OpenGL, such points would be clipped to the center. That is, if the center is off screen, they are culled, causing them to disappear even if part of the rasterized value would be visible. (FYI: this only happens on conforming desktop OpenGL implementations. Some desktop GL implementations ignore this rule)

OpenGL ES however explicitly doesn't do this. Point sprites are only clipped against the near/far planes, not against the sides of the view volume. Direct3D uses these rules as well.

Which rules does Apple's Metal follow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, on OS X on AMD and Nvidia GPUs, points are culled when their center falls outside the clip volume. On iOS, and OS X on Intel GPUs, points are clipped to the edges of the volume and culled only when they fall entirely outside. As this is not documented (to the best of my knowledge), it may be subject to change.

Comment: Is this true even for NVIDIA hardware on OSX? They *never* implemented the desktop GL clipping behavior.

Comment: I just tested this on Intel, and it seems to clip rather than culling. Clearly my answer needs some refinement. I'll update it when I have a chance to investigate.

Comment: After testing this further, it appears that this behavior is implementation-dependent, and varies across AMD, Intel, and Nvidia. I've updated my answer accordingly.